# Exact match using grep but also escape characters on searched string (with PHP)

Tags: php, regex, linux, unix

I have a directory called Records with a file record.txt and the file contains-

```
id=12345
name=O'Wright Inc
record1=0123456789\01234/5678912x
record2=0123456789|012345ajsdnjqw
record3=0123456789/012345ajsdnjqw
```

I have a PHP file and I'm trying to do an exact match for eg. name=O'Wright Inc.
What I have right now is-

```
echo "Enter the unique book identifier (Book ID): ";
$val = addslashes(trim(fgets(STDIN)));
$path = shell_exec("grep -rE '(^)$vals($)'");
var_dump($path);
```

If I search for id=12345, I get back `record:id=12345` which would be a correct result.
But if I search for name=O'Wright Inc, the result is NULL.

I am looking for a way to escape the `'` `|` and `\` characters. I have added the addslashes that works with a string that has `/` in it, but I want to escape and search for the other characters as well.

Update:
If I remove the `addslashes` and rewrite `$path = shell_exec("grep -rE '(^)$vals($)'");` as ->
`$path = shell_exec("grep -rE \"(^)$vals($)\"");`  then it takes care of the `'` character in the string, so a search for `name=O'Wright Inc` would return a correct result.

Is it recommended that I should handle the slashes and the pipe individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your code produces output incorrectly escaped for shell arguments, which is why [`escapeshellarg()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) exists.

You should construct your command string like so:

```php
$val = "O'Brien";
$expression = escapeshellarg("(^)$val($)");
$command = "grep -rE $expression";

var_dump($command);
```

Output:

```
string(27) "grep -rE '(^)O'\''Brien($)'"
```

Also, you don't need the parentheses around `^` and `$` in that regular expression.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly well with the a single quote in the string. But it still returns a Null if I seach for record1=0123456789\01234/5678912x   and returns all results if I search for record2=0123456789|012345ajsdnjqw.  Do I need to escape for the backslash and pipe separately so that it returns an exact match?

Comment: That is likely a different problem relating to how you're accepting and handling user input. I would suggest submitting a new question specifically regarding the new issue, and including the code that gets user input.

Comment: @manishk you need to escape any characters that are used in regular expressions, like the pipe. This sounds like an XY problem; why would you do this using `grep` and not just use PHP?

Comment: This is because the directory Records can have sub directories with an hierarchical structure, and then they have files like record.txt format. So I need to find files based on the user input which can be record1=0123456789\01234/5678912x or id=12345 (exact match).